# How can I use mongoengine.to_json() method with utf8 encoding

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, mongoengine

I have a code like this:

```
 import ast 
 objects = MenuModel.objects()
 data = ast.literal_eval(objects.to_json())
```

this code return :

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "54eab211b0b7080827f3b9d3"
        }, 
        "name": "\\u0627\\u06cc\\u0646\\u0645 \\u06cc\\u0647 \\u06cc\\u0648\\u0646\\u06cc \\u06a9\\u062f", 
    }
```

and i can't return unicode data. How can i convert "name" filed to unicode?

Comment: why do you call `ast.literal_eval()` (that expects a *Python* literal as an input) on *JSON* data (as the name `.to_json()` implies)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import json
>>> json_text = json.dumps(u'\N{ARABIC LETTER ALEF}')
>>> json_text
'"\\u0627"'
>>> #XXX WRONG DO NOT DO IT!!!
>>> import ast; ast.literal_eval(json_text)
'\\u0627'
```

Do this instead if you need to convert a json text into Python object:

```
>>> json.loads(json_text)
u'\u0627'
```

Or avoid calling `.to_json()` and work with `objects` object directly (convert it to a `dict` if necessary).